# Calling a DialogFragment from a ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, android-dialogfragment

I have an android application with a main activity extending a listactivity.

```
public class Main_activity extends ListActivity {...}
```

Out of the options menu, I want to send a part of the items via mail. To select the items, I want to display a dialogfragment.

Everything works fine, but I have to start a new intent (loosing my listview), this extending FragmentActivity, as it is not possible to use getSupportFragmentManager out of the ListActivity.

```
startActivity (new Intent (this, Fragment_Activity.class));
```

and

```
public class Fragment_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements EditNameDialogListener {...}
```

Is there any possibility to display the DialogFragment directly from my Main_activity? What do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you change Main_activity to extend [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) and move your list code to a [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html). With your main activity extending FragmentActivity it gives you the chance to show the dialog fragment without losing the ListView and the underlying data.

UPDATE: Since you don't want to change your current design I see two ways forward:

1 Move the list data out of the ListActivity and into a data model of some kind so that you don't lose it. Create a static class to hold the list data or store it in SharedPreferences.

2 Use a [custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android) instead of a DialogFragment

Comment: I haven't done anything with fragments until now. After reading a while, it doesn't sound easy. I think, I'll have to stay with my current code, until I have time to understand the fragments.
Thanks for your answer...

Comment: It really isn't that complex, but if you don't wanna do it right now I guess you will have to move the list data out of the ListActivity and into a data model of some kind so that you don't lose it. Create a static class to hold the list data or store it in SharedPreferences